# Black screen after promoting server to domain controller

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2022

I have Windows Server 2022 in its latest version 21H2. I installed a Domain Name System server + Active Directory Domain Services on the server and promoted it to a domain controller.

After the automatic restart of the server, a black screen with a rotating wheel will appear and this state will remain forever.

The server is virtualized using the type-1 hypervisor Proxmox Virtual Environment. I use Red Hat Virtual Machine Manager as a virtual machine monitor and a SPICE client to connect to the virtual machine remotely.

The server is not yet activated.

---

I think it might have something to do with the updates that were automatically installed when the server automatically restarted after it was promoted to a domain controller or it might have something to do with the Active Directory module.

In the past, a similar problem occurred after installing the Windows security update KB5009555 released 11.1. 2022 when the server went into an infinite boot loop after restarting. This problem was later fixed in Windows update KB5010796 released on 17.1. 2022 or by manually removing it from safe mode using the command:

`wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:5009555 /quiet /forcerestart`

Comment: Windows Server 2022 will automatically uninstall any problematic updates if a restart is unsuccessful. I just installed a 2022 DC with the minimum 2 CPU and 2 GB memory and there's no problem at all.  You may want to spend a few minutes and compare this installation to an installation on more orthodox hardware/hypervisor (e.g. Hyper-V).